# Load avro decimal data into BigQuery?

Tags: hive, google-bigquery, avro

I have AVRO hive-table which has some columns as decimal.I know How Avro store the decimal data that is in Logical-type format.But When i load these data into BigQuery, BigQuery is not able to parse these decimal data it treat them like garbage value.I don't know to load these decimal data into BigQuery.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please [file a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) and attach a sample Avro file that does not contain PII, if possible?

Answer (score 3):

With AVRO_DECIMAL type being a relatively recent addition, BigQuery doesn's support it yet. Here's the issuetracker link:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65641870

As a temporary workaround you can convert your decimal data to a floating point representation so it can be loaded into BigQuery.

Comment: We have Decimal datatype under the Array of Struct datatype like Array<<Struct<<decimal>>>> , in this case we can't convert into other types.